# CSS not working on Google ads placed in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to place a horizontal 970x90 ad at the top and 2 160x600 ads on the right side one below another.

This is how my page looks like without ads.

[image: This is how my page looks like without ads.]

Here is my HTML without ads

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 2 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 3 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 4 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 5 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 6 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 7 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 8 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 9 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 10 -->
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

This is my HTML with ads included

```
<div class="container">
    <div align="center">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- edm-top -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:inline-block;width:970px;height:90px"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 2 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 3 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 4 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 5 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="edm-sides" align="right">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- edm-sides -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="edm-sides" align="right">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- edm-sides -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 6 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 7 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 8 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 9 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <!-- DJ 10 -->
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.edm-sides {
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Here is how the page looks

[image: Here is how the page looks]

The CSS seems to be having no effect on the google ad in the div. What's wrong here?

Also what would be the easiest way to put the DJ columns one below another without leaving that space between the 1st and 2nd row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve what you're trying to do you need to change a couple of things,
- create a main container that will have the DJs class="col-md-9"
- create a sidebar to put your ads class="col-md-3"

then inside the main container create a div.col-md-12 or div.row so that it takes all the width, this will act as a row and inside of it you can put DJ 1 to 5, and every new row that you want you can do create it this way.

you need to resize the container in fiddle to be able to see it

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/52VtD/2274/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        ad
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <!-- DJ info -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
             DJ 1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 3 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 4 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 5 -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
             DJ 6 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 7 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 8 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 9 -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
                 DJ 10 -->
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- DJ info end-->
    </div>
    <!-- ADS side bar -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-center">
        <div>
              ad1  
        </div>
        <div>
            ad2
        </div>
    <!-- ADS side bar end -->
    </div>
</div>
```